# Devops Build Issue for asp.net core 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have created Devops project in Azure it is using ASP.NET core 1.x version.

I have updated this project to ASP.NET core 2.x after updating I am getting build issue in my Vsts.

Do I need to change any setting in CI?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing? I suggest you, refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

In your build definition on VSTS, inside: Use .NET Core Installer step, you will need to change the version of .NET Core from 1.0.4 to whichever version of .NET 2.X you are using.

So for example you could change that to 2.1.105 which is the latest version of 2 and will build any current 2.x version.

[image: Version change]